# Insufficient free space error on PS3 after trying to install two games

Tags: ps3

I purchased a PS3 from a Pound Shop that had the previous user's data on it. After deleting all the previous user's data from the system, I was able to download a game and play it. My son has another game that he would like to play; however, when I try to install it, it says the system does not have enough free space. I tried resetting the system multiple times, but to no avail. Do I have to uninstall a game every time I want to install a new one? There's another PS3 that is the same model as the one I own, and that one can hold five games without any issues. What do I need to do in order to install multiple games on my PS3?

Comment: What games?  Some older PS3s had very small disks (20GB) and some modern games are very large, so it is possible that two AAA games would not fit.

Comment: How much space and what games are we talking about here? Sometimes you'll get this error if you don't have at least double the space that the game actually needs.

Answer (score 1):

The PS3 can come with an extremely small HDD. You can buy a bigger hard drive, however you'll need to know how to replace it. You can find a lot of videos on how to do this online.

Here's a PS3 HDD that I found just by doing a quick search on Amazon: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00SWXYDBY and this tutorial should help: